# Single entry web apps in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Can someone please point to some docs or links which show how to create a single entry point ( similar to CMS like Joomla ) web app in Rails. I need to create a web app in Rails where there will a lot of places which will have restricted access based on whether the logged in user has paid for that functionality.

Comment: Your question is a bit too generic. You should provide more information. For example: Do you have any Rails experience? Will you need the rails app to interact with Banks in order to confirm payments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may wanna see [Authorization with CanCan](http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan) and [Declarative Authorization](http://railscasts.com/episodes/188-declarative-authorization) screen casts.

Answer (score 0):

Get familiar with [ActionController::Filters::ClassMethods #before_filter](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Filters/ClassMethods.html#M000526). You can create one controller that has a `before_filter` which handles all your ACS needs. Then you can extend that controller to implement specific ACS-restricted actions.